# How do I edit the default chart styles in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, charts, coldfusion-9, pie-chart

I know that I can use WebCharts3d to create new styles, but I'd love to be able to slightly tweak the default PIE chart type in CF. If I open either the beige_pie.cml or red_pie.xml in \Coldfusion9\Charting\Styles, they are DRASTICALLY different than the default appearance. Is there any way to get access to the DEFAULT pie styles?

Comment: I don't use CF9 but if you can access the xml for the chart - red_pie.xml - why just not copy it, change what you need and use it with WebCharts3d?

Comment: The style for red_pie is substantially different from the default set -- fonts, color series, etc. I would prefer not to have to reverse engineer all of the details of the built-in CF options.

Comment: @Chris - Did you try the "default" styles ie "default_pie.xml" or "default.xml"?

Comment: Have you ever had one of those moments where you wish you could crawl into a hole? I would vote to remove the question -- but I dont' want to deprive you of knowing that that was my major malfuncion... Thanks Leigh.

Comment: @Chris - Often ;) The important part is that you have it working. Cheers

Comment: Leigh, you should post that as an answer, and Chris, you should accept it. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via comment from Leigh -

default_pie.xml and default.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Google Charts?

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Take the load off your cf server and outsource them to Google :)
Unless of course, you have a ton of free memory...

There's heaps to choose from. eg.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html